# Pattern substring from string {duplicate}

Tags: bash

I have read the related question on quora on how to find pattern based substring but did not able to successfully implement on my use case

I have strings like these

```
https://$(test.url)/bbmap-oautsdsdh-prdswdovdsdsdider/oausdsdth2/tokedsdsdn
$(test2.url)/b123bmap-oautsd212sdh-prdswd343ovdsdsdider/oausdsdth2/tokedsdsdn
https://$(test3.url)/bbmap-oautdsdsdsdh-prdswdosdvdsdsdider/oausdsdtsdh2/sd
```

I am writing regex to grab these substring

```
test.url
test2.url
test3.url
```

I have written these scripts. Please let me know what I am missing?

```
my_var='https://$(test.url)/bbmap-oautsdsdh-prdswdovdsdsdider/oausdsdth2/tokedsdsdn'
echo $my_var | awk -F[\(\)] '{print $2}'

Expected output:
test.url
```

Comment: Why did you put "{duplicate}" in your title?

Comment: There are other questions similar to mine but none of them solved my issue, it is for disclaimer purposes only

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Nor where is the regular expression you've mentioned. But I am pretty sure the line ```my_var = yq ...``` is not what you want. That line just build a string, literaly the string "yq ,securityEtc", and store it in ```$my_var```. I surmise that you are trying to get in ```my_var``` the result of ```yq``` command called with arguments ```.securityEtc```. So the construct for that is ```my_var=$(yq etc)``` not ```my_var=yq etc```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I have simplified it

Comment: In fact, because of the space after = (```my_var= yq```) it would not store the string "yq ..." in my_var neither. my_var would be empty. And yq command is executed

Comment: Well, that new version wouldn't work neither. Because of the ```$(test.url)```. Even between double quotes, that would be expanded to the result of a ```test.url``` command, and I don't think you have a "test.url" command. That is just a pattern, right?

Comment: Considering the my_var as string I am just trying to grab the substring that is between $()

yes @chrslg

Comment: So, maybe you should enclose your my_var variable in simple quotes

Comment: With simple quotes, it works fine. It displays ```test.url``` as intended then

Comment: Note that syntax coloring of stackoverflow bash quote gave you an hint: ```$(test.url)``` appears in black, not green like literal string.

Comment: Well, yes, but now is there a question left? I mean, the expected value is precisely the value you get from your updated code, isn't it?

Comment: yes, I tried again seems like white space issue